Flutter assets will be downloaded from https://storage.flutter-io.cn. Make sure you trust this source
I had problem in downloading flutter packages by flutter pub get and I solved it by adding these two env variables to user env variables:
FLUTTER_STORAGE_BASE_URL
https://storage.flutter-io.cn


PUB_HOSTED_URL
https://pub.flutter-io.cn

But now I want to reset these settings and use the original addresses for the flutter packages to get downloaded. I have removed the mentioned key values from env, but it's still using https://pub.flutter-io.cn and I get Flutter assets will be downloaded from https://storage.flutter-io.cn. Make sure you trust this source! warning. How can I use the original address for flutter packages?
